# AppsFlyer SDK integration

Tags: android, appsflyer, appsflyer-android-sdk

I have added AppsFlyer SDK in application. Below is the code which i have added in the application:

In Application class:

```
 AppsFlyerConversionListener conversionDataListener =
                new AppsFlyerConversionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInstallConversionDataLoaded(Map<String, String> conversionData) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInstallConversionFailure(String errorMessage) {
                        Log.d(AppsFlyerLib.LOG_TAG, "error getting conversion data: " + errorMessage);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAppOpenAttribution(Map<String, String> attributionData) {
                        Log.d(AppsFlyerLib.LOG_TAG, "DEEP LINK WORKING");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAttributionFailure(String errorMessage) {
                        Log.d(AppsFlyerLib.LOG_TAG, "error onAttributionFailure : " + errorMessage);
                    }
                };


AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().startTracking(this, "DEV_KEY");
```

In manifest :

```
<receiver android:name="com.appsflyer.SingleInstallBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In Activity for track event :

```
Map<String, Object> eventValue = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    eventValue.put("login", "member");
AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().trackEvent(getApplicationContext(), "event_login", eventValue);
```

**I am not able to view the event in AppsFlyer dashboard. Also not able to view custom parameters of event.**

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: have you found solution?

Comment: Yes do you need any help?

Comment: @Annie, can you leave the answer if you have found it, please? :) I'd appreciate it so much

Comment: @zeroDivider this code is working perfectly. to check the event just need to download appsflyer sdk application in device and connect it to our application. then you will be able to see events in appsflyer as non organic events. this is just like a debug view of firebase. please let me know if any query.

Comment: @VishvaDave yeah, I got that later :/ it took me a while, but I've seen in the log that my device is not whitelisted.. but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Were you able to see custom parameters in the dashboard? Does Appsflyer support them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device is probably not whitelisted. As mentioned [here](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207031996--Whitelisting-a-Test-Device), *test devices* should be whitelisted via AppsFlyer's app `My Device ID by AppsFlyer`.